# Size limitation when drawing to CanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

**I HAVE HEAVILY EDITED THIS QUESTION TO PROVIDE MORE DETAILS**

I came across a limitation when drawing to CanvasRenderingContext2D via EaselJS framework. I have objects like this:

[image]

but when the position of those objects surpasses couple million pixels the drawings start to crumble apart. This is the same object with x position 58524928. (The parent container is moved to -58524928 so that we can see the object on stage.) The more I offset the object the more it will crumble. Also when I try to move the object - drag it with mouse - it will "jump" like it was subjected to a large grid.

[image]

This is EaseJS framework and the shapes are ultimately drawn to the CanvasRenderingContext2D via the drawImage() method. Here is snippet from the code:

<strike>ctx.drawImage(cacheCanvas, this._cacheOffsetX+this._filterOffsetX, this._cacheOffsetY+this._filterOffsetY, cacheCanvas.width/scale, cacheCanvas.height/scale);</strike>

I suppose it has something to do with the limited number of real numbers in JavaScript:

> Note that there are infinitely many real numbers, but only a finite
>   number of them (18437736874454810627, to be exact) can be represented
>   exactly by the JavaScript floating-point format. This means that when
>   you're working with real numbers in JavaScript, the representation of
>   the number will often be an approximation of the actual number.

Source: [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch03_01.htm#jscript4-CHP-3-SECT-1)

Can someone confirm/reject my assumption? 58 million (58524928) does not seems so much to me, is it some inefficiency of EaselJS or it is a limit of the Canvas?

PS:
Scaling has no effect. I have drawn everything 1000 times smaller and 1000 times closer with no effect. Equally, if you scale the object up 1000 times while still x:58 million it will not look crumbled. But move it to 50 billion and you are where you started. Basically offset divided by size is constant limit for details.

EDIT

Here is example jsfiddle.net/wzbsbtgc/2. Basically there are two separate problems

1. If I use huge numbers as parameters for the drawing itself (red curve) it will be distorted. This can be avoided by using smaller numbers and moving the DisplayObject instead (blue curve).
2. In both cases it is not possible to move the DisplayObject by 1px. I think this is explained in GameAlchemist's post.

Any advice/workaround for the second problem is welcome.

Comment: scaling has no effect. I have drawn everything 1000 times smaller and 1000 times closer with no effect. Equally, if you scale the object up 1000 times while still x:58 million it will not look crumbled. Move it to 50 billion and you are where you started. Basically offset*size is constant limit for details.

Comment: Can you confirm that the Shape instance that is drawing incorrectly is cached (via the `cache()` method)? From the image you provided, it looks like a vector draw where the values are getting messed up, but you are posting code from EaselJS's cached content drawing routine. I want to confirm what you're doing so that I can try to reproduce.

Comment: Hi Grant, no the drawing is not cached, what you say means I made a mistake by posting the snipped here. Here is why I need to draw so many details on such large canvas http://wikibudgets.org/w/uk/london/greenwich/2015/. Btw I am your great fun from the Flash age :)

Comment: So, I attempted to reproduce this, but I'm able to use crazy high numbers (ex. 6.234e+28) without any issue. Any chance you could try to isolate the problem in a JSFiddle, and I'd be happy to take another look? http://jsfiddle.net/8r4zn1af/1/

Comment: hmm I can't reproduce it. I am going to work on it and I will provide you clean example tonight. Thanks

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/wzbsbtgc/2/. Basically there are two separate problems 1/If I use huge numbers as parameters for the curve (red curve) it will be distorted. This can be avoided by using smaller numbers and moving the DisplayObject instead (blue curve). 2/ In both cases it is not possible to move the DisplayObject by 1px. I think this is explained in GameAlchemist's post. Any advice/workaround for problem 2 is welcome.

Comment: Interesting. Definitely looks like some kind of browser limitation. Maybe it is using lower precision values for canvas. EaselJS is literally just calling Context2D methods with the exact values you're passing in. Also worth noting that Chrome does FAR worse with this test than FF, IE or Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Context2D uses lower precision numbers for transforms. I haven't confirmed the precision yet, but my guess is that it is using floats instead of doubles.

As such, with higher values, the `transform` method (and other similar C2D methods) that EaselJS relies on loses precision, similar to what GameAlchemist describes. You can see this issue reproduced using pure C2D calls here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9fLff2we/

The best workaround that I can think of, would be to precalculate the "final" values external to the transform methods. Normal JS numbers are higher precision than what C2D is using, so this should solve the issue. Really rough example to illustrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/wzbsbtgc/3/

Comment: The Context2D spec lists the transform params as floats, which means it is using 32b floats instead of the 64b doubles used for normal JS Number instances. `void transform(in float m11, in float m12, in float m21, in float m22, in float dx, in float dy);`

Comment: I think I you are right, that's the way out of this. I can see 3 instances of ctx.transform() in the DO's updateContext function,  I am going to try to hack my way through your code :). I wonder what will be the performance penalty for doing the transforms in JS. PS: I wish you wrote CreateJS in TypeScript.

Comment: There are decent TypeScript definition files for CreateJS out there. For example: https://github.com/elsassph/createjs-def

While I really like TS, writing in JS and having def files makes the libraries accessible to a much broader market.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not correct. The standard defines transforms as *unrestricted doubles*: From the spec: `void setTransform(unrestricted double a, unrestricted double b, unrestricted double c, unrestricted double d, unrestricted double e, unrestricted double f);` Source: [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#2dcontext). But perhaps the old version stated floats? Could you link to the source?

Comment: You are correct, this is from an [old version of the draft spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-2dcontext-20100624/), but based on the issues outlined in this post, it looks like browser manufacturers may not have updated yet.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior that you see is related to the way figures are represented in the IEEE 754 standard.

While Javascript uses 64bits floats, WebGL uses only 32bits float, and since most (?all?) canvases are webGL accelerated, all your numbers will be (down)converted before the draw.

The IEEE 754 32 bits standard uses 32 bits to represent a number : 1 bit for sign, 8 exponent bits, and then only 23 bits for the mantissa.

Let's call IEEE_754_32max :

```
 IEEE_754_32max = ( 1 << 23 ) -1 = 8.388.6071  (8+ millions)
```

We can have full precision for integers only in the `[-IEEE_754_32max, IEEE_754_32max]` range.
Beyond that point, the exponent will be used, and we'll loose the weak bits of the mantissa.

For instance ( 10 millions + 1 ) = 10.000.001 is too big, it can't fit into 23 bits,so it will be stored as

```
    10.000.001 = 10.000.00• * 10 = 1e7 = 10.000.000
```

- We lost the final '1' -

The grid effect that you see is linked to the exponent being used /precision being lost : with figures such as 58524928, we need 26 bits to represent the figure. So 3 bits are lost, and we have, for instance :

```
 58524928 + 7 == 58524928
```

So when using a figure that is near from 58524928, it will either be rounded to 58524928, OR 'jump' to the nearest possible figure : you have your grid effect.

Solution ?
-->> Change the units you are using for your applications, to have much smaller figures. Maybe you're using mm --> use meters or kilometers.
Mind that the precision you are using is an illusion : display resolution is the first limit, and the mouse is 1 pixel precise at most, so even with a 4K display, there's no way 32 bit floats can be a limit.

Choose the right measure unit to fit your all your coordinates in a smaller range and you'll solve your issue.

More clearly : you *must* change the units you are using *for the display*. Which does not mean you have to trade accuracy : you just have to do the translation + scaling by yourself before drawing : that way you still use the Javascript IEEE 64 bits accuracy and you've got no more those 32 bits rounding issue.

(you might override the x, y properties with getters/setters

```
Object.defineProperty(targetObject, 'x', { get : function() { return view.pixelWidth*(this.rx-view.left)/view.width ;  } }
```

)

Comment: @GameAlchemist I think you nailed it. Unfortunately I can not simply change the units, I really need to draw that many details to Canvas. See http://wikibudgets.org/w/uk/london/greenwich/2015/. I am trying to find reasonable workaround. Maybe I will fake-move or fake-scale the current view when it get's too far from the centre but doing it in such way so the diagram stays consistent at EVERY zoom level is ... tricky. Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use any sized drawing coordinates that you desire.**

Canvas will clip your drawing to the display area of the canvas element.

For example, here's a demo that starts drawing a line from x = -50000000 and finishes on the canvas. Only the visible portion of the line is rendered. All non-visible (off-canvas) points are clipped.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(-50000000,100);
ctx.lineTo(150,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>This line starts at x = negative 50 million!</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: hi @markE, I have heavily re-edited the question, what do you think now?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the target audience for W3C standard is mainly browser vendors. The unsigned long value (or 2<sup>32</sup>) addresses more the underlying system for creating a bitmap by the browser. The standard says values in this range are valid, but there is no guarantee the underlying system will be able to provide a bitmap that large (most browsers today limits the bitmap to much smaller sizes than this). You stated that you don't mean the canvas element itself, but the link reference is the interface definition of the element so I just wanted to point that out in regards to the number range.

From the JavaScript side of things, where we developers usually are, and with the exception of typed arrays, there is no such thing as ulong etc. Only `Number` (aka `unrestricted double`) which is signed and stores numbers in 64-bit, formatted as IEEE-754.

The valid range for `Number` is:

```
Number.MIN_VALUE = 5e-324
Number.MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

You can use any values in this range with canvas for your vector paths. Canvas will clip them to the bitmap based on the current transformation matrix when the paths are rasterized.

If you by drawing mean another *bitmap* (ie. Image, Canvas, Video) then they will be subject to the same system and browser capabilities/restrictions as the target canvas itself. Positioning (direct or via transformation) is limited (in sum) by the range of a Number.

Comment: hi @ken, I have heavily re-edited the question, what do you think now?

Comment: I think this answer perhaps is rendered irrelevant after the question was changed :) I can leave it as a general reference though.